# ERRO null with sqlite and java

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, sqlitemanager

I am developing java application in netbeans. I connected database sqlite and it works perfectly. Now, i am trying to delete a field in database:

```
public void delete(){
    dbo.openConnection();
    String sqlCommand = "DELETE FROM restaurante WHERE id_restaurante = " + this.id_restaurante;
    System.out.println(sqlCommand);
    dbo.executeSQL(sqlCommand);
    dbo.closeConnection();
}
```

When i execute this method, i get this error:

```
DELETE FROM restaurante WHERE id_restaurante = 4
ERRO null
```

...and the field doesn't delete in database.

If i copy this line: `DELETE FROM restaurante WHERE id_restaurante = 4` and try delete in sqlite manager (add-on firefox), works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
String sqlCommand = "DELETE FROM `restaurante` WHERE `id_restaurante` = " + this.id_restaurante;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is ERRO null ??? Is it a stack trace uncomplete or something you write yourself ?
I guess for the second solution, something is wrong in the method

```
dbo.executeSQL(sqlCommand);
```

Debug or add log.
Check that :

1. Connection is correctly open.
2. Check that there is no null pointer in the method abobe. I am nearly sure that is the problem.
3. Check that you have the right to delete with the connection in your program.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
String sqlCommand = "DELETE FROM restaurante WHERE id_restaurante = '" +id_restaurante+"'";
```